# Python 3.5 type annotated variable without initial value

Tags: python, python-3.5, mypy, typechecking

I need to declare global variables that have "complex" type and *should not* be instantiated at import time. In Python 3.6+, I can omit initialization, for example:

```
log: logging.Logger
pollset: select.poll
```

I need to make the code compatible with Python 3.5. I can use comment type annotations:

```
log = ...  # type: logging.Logger
pollset = ...  # type: select.poll
```

but then I have to provide initial value. This is not a problem at runtime, assigning the initial value of `None` or `...` will do. But any of those trigger mypy typecheck error:

> myprog.py:19: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ellipsis", variable has type "Logger")

Of course I could use `Optional` type to allow initializing to `None`, but then type checking would be weakened. For instance, assigning `None` value to the variable elsewhere in the code is illegal, but it would not be caught.

Is there an accepted way to use strong type checking of a variable in a way that is compatible with Python 3.5?

Comment: Perhaps just the comment?

Comment: Python doesn't *have* variable declarations, only variable *definitions*.  What do you *really* "need" to do?

Comment: After `log: logging.Logger`, there is still no variable named `log`.

Comment: @chepner A variable annotation is enough to create said variable if that is meaningful for its scope. In a local scope, it creates an unbound local variable. "However, annotating a local variable will cause the interpreter to always make it a local:". https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#global-and-local-variable-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique you could do is create a dummy variable with type `Any`, then use that instead of setting your variables to `...` or `None`. For example:

```
from typing import Any

_bogus = None     # type: Any
log = _bogus      # type: logging.Logger
pollset = _bogus  # type: select.poll
```

However, this solution isn't perfect. With variable annotations, we avoided actually creating assigning a value to these variables, so attempting to use `log` before it's instantiated would result in a NameError at runtime.

However, with this approach, we'd instead get `None`, which contradicts our declared type.

Maybe this is ok for your use case, but if it isn't, we can get something closer to the variable annotations behavior by sticking these inside of a `if TYPE_CHECKING` block:

```
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    _bogus = None     # type: Any
    log = _bogus      # type: logging.Logger
    pollset = _bogus  # type: select.poll
```

The `TYPE_CHECKING` variable is always False at runtime, but treated as if it were True by type-checkers like mypy.

(Doing `if False` also works. It's a common-enough convention that mypy directly supports that as an alternative to using `TYPE_CHECKING`.)

Answer (score 4):

According to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments), assigning `None` is correct.

```
log = None  # type: logging.Logger
```

---

Note that `mypy` [only allows this at class scope](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2179). However, you can declare a type *and* tell `mypy` to ignore the assignment itself ([since `mypy` 0.700](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2019/04/mypy-0700-released-up-to-4x-faster.html)).

```
log = None  # type: logging.Logger  # type: ignore
```

Also, you can use a `.pyi` stub file regardless of Python version.

```
# my_lib.pyi
log: logging.Logger
```

---

> However, in non-stub code for versions of Python 3.5 and earlier there is a special case:
>
> ```
> from typing import IO
>
> stream = None  # type: IO[str]
> ```
>
> Type checkers should not complain about this (despite the value None not matching the given type), nor should they change the inferred type to Optional[...] (despite the rule that does this for annotated arguments with a default value of None). The assumption here is that other code will ensure that the variable is given a value of the proper type, and all uses can assume that the variable has the given type.

---

Comment: All this should work according to the PEP, but unfortunately mypy (0.670) does not honour the exception and complains, both if I assign `None` and if I add the `# type: ignore`.

Comment: @crosser I've verified it with ``mypy`` 0.701. You can test it directly with ``mypy -c 'foo = None  # type: int # type: ignore'`` from the terminal.

Comment: @crosser You need at least ``mypy`` 0.700 for this. See the updated answer.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the clarification. I will still go with the suggestion from the other answer for the sake of wider compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The special treatment of `None` for PEP 484 was decided in [python/typing#61](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/61). Sadly, the type checkers (I tried mypy and pyre) don't implement this. The problem is further discussed in [python/typing#81](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/81).

There are workarounds that can be used

1. Cast the `None`, or ellipsis, to the correct dynamic type. This will placate both mypy and pyre.

```
self.process: subprocess.Popen = cast(subprocess.Popen, None)
self.process: subprocess.Popen = cast(subprocess.Popen, ...)
```

2. Suppress the check with a comment, essentially the same effect as before, but nicer to write.

```
self.process: subprocess.Popen = None  # type: ignore
```

3. Declare the variable `Optional[...]`, and then do checks for `None` on every access

```
self.process: Optional[subprocess.Popen] = None
```